# iOS toolbar above keyboard position not correct

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard

My App Most of pages is Landscape, only a few pages are Portrait. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHGaO.png) shows my problem. In the case of Portrait, the position of the toolbar above keyboard/date-picker is not correct.
I set device orientations are Portrait/Landscape Left/Landscape Right. And in Portrait page my code

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    if ([NSObject isiPhone]) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    if ([NSObject isiPhone]) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return YES;
}
```

The follow are my toolbar code:

```
    UIToolbar *toolbar=[[UIToolbar alloc]init]; 
    toolbar.barTintColor=[UIColor lightTextColor]; 
    toolbar.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44); 
    UIBarButtonItem *item2=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *item3=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(click)];
    toolbar.items = @[item2,item3]; 
    self.babyBirthdayTextfield.inputAccessoryView=toolbar;
```

The issue also occurred on web view
 [my app Portrait view's structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEBZ6.png)

I have fixed the problem. The root controller of this storyboard is a modal window. Changing the segue's kind.

Comment: Please add some more code regarding how you are adding toolbar to your keyboard

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to manage frame of the toolbar manually. Just use textField's `inputAccessoryView` and you are good to go:

```
UIToolbar* toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];
toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
toolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancelButtonTapped)],
                       [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                       [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(doneButtonTapped)],
                       nil];
[toolbar sizeToFit];
self.textField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What problem are you facing when you use this code?

Comment: Add some more code how you are adding your toolbar currently

Comment: @alulkhatri I add more info for the question.